# How to match a string exactly OR exact substring from beginning using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm trying to build a regex query for a database and it's got me stumped. If I have a string with a varying number of elements that has an ordered structure how can I find if it matches another string exactly OR some exact sub string when read from the left?

For example I have these strings

1. Canada.Ontario.Toronto.Downtown
2. Canada.Ontario
3. Canada.EasternCanada.Ontario.Toronto.Downtown
4. England.London
5. France.SouthFrance.Nice

They are structured by most general location to specific, left to right. However, the number of elements varies with some specifying a country.region.state and so on, and some just country.town. I need to match not only the words but the order.

So if I want to match "Canada.Ontario.Toronto.Downtown" I would want to both get #1 and #2 and nothing else. How would I do that? Basically running through the string and as soon as a different character comes up it's not a match but still allow a sub string that ends "early" to match like #2.

I've tried making groups and using "?" like (canada)?.?(Ontario)?.? etc but it doesn't seem to work in all situations since it can match nothing as well.

Edit as requested:
Mongodb Database Collection:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "doc1",
        "context": "Canada.Ontario.Toronto.Downtown",
        "useful_data": "Some Data"
    },
    {
        "_id": "doc2",
        "context": "Canada.Ontario",
        "useful_data": "Some Data"
    },
    {
        "_id": "doc3",
        "context": "Canada.EasternCanada.Ontario.Toronto.Downtown",
        "useful_data": "Some Data"
    },
    {
        "_id": "doc4",
        "context": "England.London",
        "useful_data": "Some Data"
    },
    {
        "_id": "doc5",
        "context": "France.SouthFrance.Nice",
        "useful_data": "Some Data"
    },
    {
        "_id": "doc6",
        "context": "",
        "useful_data": "Some Data"
    }
]
```

User provides "Canada", "Ontario", "Toronto", and "Downtown" values in that order and I need to use that to query doc1 and doc2 and no others. So I need a regex pattern to put in here: `collection.find({"context": {$regex: <pattern here>})` If it's not possible I'll just have to restructure the data and use different methods of finding those docs.

Comment: Regular expression matching has a regex pattern opposite to a string of symbols. If you want to use regular expressions, you have to make up your mind which is which in your situation.  Is the database of city locations a set of regexes, with the search key being a string? Or is the search key supposed to be a regex against a database of strings?

Comment: The search key will be a regex and it matches against the database string values. I'm using mongodb which is a database of json documents(not relational). Each document would have a key "context" and the value of that key would be a string like the ones above. mongodb supports using a regex pattern for querying string fields in the each document in the database. I'll edit my question with an example db I guess, but I felt the implementation would cloud the question. All I really need is a regex pattern that will generate a match for strings 1 and 2 and not the rest.

Comment: So must start with `Canada` optionally followed  by any of the words in exact order[...like this demo?](https://regex101.com/r/ZHAcR0/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble yup that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each dot, start an nested optional group for the next term, and add start and end anchors:

```
^Canada(\.Ontario(\.Toronto(\.Downtown)?)?)?$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/pqpoBkWvYZvtMY).